# Scraping number of retweets using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I am using Beautifulsoup for scraping twitter data and i want to scrape number of retweets for each tweet and my below is my code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://twitter.com/nokia"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
tweets = soup.findAll('li',{"class":'js-stream-item'})
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.find('p',{"class":'tweet-text'}):
        tweet_user = tweet.find('span',{"class":'username'}).text
        tweet_text = tweet.find('p',{"class":'tweet-text'}).text.encode('utf8')
        retweets = tweet.find('span',{"class":"ProfileTweet-actionCount"}).text
        print(tweet_user)
        print(tweet_text)
        print(retweets)
    else:
        continue
```

I am able to get tweet_user and tweet_text but some how not able to get number of retweets can someone explain me how to get number of retweets

Comment: Not an answer, but this could be much easier achieved using the Twitter API!

Comment: yes i know that but api has a rate limit and moreover you can get tweets for not more than 7 days before

Comment: As far as I know you can get the 3 200 last tweets, no matter how old. At least a few weeks ago, last time I tried!

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using tweepy is encouraged
Your code with little modifications:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://twitter.com/nokia"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
tweets = soup.findAll('li',{"class":'js-stream-item'})
for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet.find('p',{"class":'tweet-text'}):
        tweet_user = tweet.find('span',{"class":'username'}).text.strip()
        tweet_text = tweet.find('p',{"class":'tweet-text'}).text.encode('utf8').strip()
        replies = tweet.find('span',{"class":"ProfileTweet-actionCount"}).text.strip()
        retweets = tweet.find('span', {"class" : "ProfileTweet-action--retweet"}).text.strip()
        print(tweet_user)
        print(tweet_text)
        print(replies)
        print(retweets)
    else:
        continue
```